‘Ingress has not yet been reconciled'
We currently have two projects set up on 4.x openshift cluster. First works fine, second wont go into ready state with errors
 message: Ingress has not yet been reconciled.
  reason: IngressNotConfigured

I noticed https://knative.dev/docs/serving/setting-up-custom-ingress-gateway/#step-3-update-the-gateway-configmap this page suggests a custom ingress.
I dont expect a full answer but if someone can point me in the right direction, that'd be lovely.

There are several different possible causes (not just custom external gateways).  The core reason behind the message is that there doesn't seem to be a running controller for the ingress.networking.internal.knative.dev type and the specific Ingress class you've chosen.
https://knative.dev/docs/serving/services/ingress-class/ has general details on choosing an Ingress class; you might try listing the actual definition of the working and non-working Ingress classes to see how they differ.
You should also check that you don't have any crashing controllers in your cluster (for example, if other types they depend on haven't been loaded yet).
